# How do I make a real-time updating grid in c++

Tags: c++

So I'm making a sudoku solver to kind of test myself, and I have seem to hit a wall.

I'm trying to get the user to input values into a grid, and it'll automatically update every couple of seconds to see the next value they put in the grid.

I don't know how to get the user input into the grid itself.

Here is my code for the grid itself.

```
void draw()
{
int given;
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            cout << "|";
        }
        if (j == 3 || j == 6 || j == 9 )
        {
            cout << "|";
        }
        if (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 12)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

}

To get this to refresh, I have this loop.

```
while (gameOver != TRUE)
{
    system("cls");
    draw();
    cout << "\nEnter the next given number, or 0 for a blank space: ";
    Sleep(600);
}
```

So I need help getting the user input value to both

1. Display on the grid
2. Save in any way (I think an array might work best?)

Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a Minesweeper in Windows console and I can somehow remember whatever the tricks I've used.

Comment: Post some code how you're implementing user input or we can't look into further.

Comment: You really want to use some sort of display system. Curses is the classic solution for terminals. It depends on the platform you are using, but trying to do this with iostream is going to be deeply unsatisfying.

Comment: @iBug I don't have the slightest clue on how to get this user input.

Comment: @ZalmanStern If i dont figure this out with iostream im going to look into a display system, but I'm trying to do this with the things I've used in my c++ class.

Comment: @ZalmanStern Are you sure you want to suggest Curses to a Windows programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think that the easiest way to visualize (and store) the values would be in a two-dimensional array.

You can declare and n * m array like this :

```
int x[n][m];
```

Then access elements (i,j) like this in your for loop to display it :

```
x[i][j]
```

Comment: This uses VLA, which are not part of the Standard C++ language.  You'll have to use `std::vector` or `std::array` or dynamically allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

By this line I guess you're programming on Windows:

```
system("cls");
```

So my answer will be based on that and utilize a lot of WinAPI.

Normally, you can stick to `cin` and update the grid after user presses Enter. But since you want a real-time display refresh, this doesn't seem optimal. You have `conio.h` on Windows so go for it:

```
#include <conio.h>
...
char ch;
while (true) {
    while (!kbhit()); // Wait for user input
    ch = getch();
    switch (ch) {
        // Process input here.
    }
}
```